# How to let user define SQL parameters (in terminal) in Rmarkdown?

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, dplyr, readline

I am working to make R more user friendly. I am using `library(RODBC)` function to have direct access to the SQL database from RStudio. In markdown I use code something like this:

```
sql <- "
Select [A]
      ,[year]
      ,[model]
     ....

from
(SELECT ....
  Where  [year] between 2010 and 2020 and model ='1A' and [A] between 11 and 22... "
```

I need to let the user specify parameters from the last line (for instance 2010...2020  , '1A' and 11 ...22) in the terminal by using `readline()` function.

Comment: Hmm maybe you could use my package **aceEditor**. With this package you will be able to integrate the **ace** editor (which is the same editor as the one used by RStudio) in a Rmarkdown document (as every HTML widget). But then you want to get the parameters of the user and proceed them? You will need to use a Shiny document or a standalone document with some JavaScript code.

Comment: Does the _user_ somehow call `rmarkdown::render`? Do they click the "Knit" button in RStudio?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best option, but you can simply ask for some inputs before,

```
range_start <- readline("Range start: ")
range_end <- readline("Range start: ")
literal_and <- "and"
sql_stmt <- "select year, model from where year between"
```

and then concatenate them in one query

```
final_sql <- paste(sql_stmt, range_start, literal_and, range_end)
```

Comment: One should never `paste` data into a SQL statement. In addition to security concerns about *malicious* [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one data analyst running the query. (Unfortunately `RODBC` (in the OP) has not support for this, I recommend `DBI`+`odbc` over `RODBC` because of this.)

Comment: how can I use DBI+odbc? Never used that